# Web Api2 OAuth Bearer token lifetime management

Tags: oauth-2.0, asp.net-web-api2, owin, bearer-token

Bearer token does not get invalidated. Even if a new bearer token is issued for the same user, the old token is still valid and can be used to access to API resources.

How can we restrict(or make a workaround) for this.

I have an angular application and my ASP.NET Web API also lives in the same domain and it uses Token based authentication which is very similar to the scaffold template boilerplate code from Visual Studio for Web API with Individual Authentication. Authentication is against Windows AD and slight changes are made for that in the GrantResourceOwnerCredentials of OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider implementation.

Issues, I believe, are:

1) A bearer token once generated does not get invalidated even if the credentials are changed.

2) A bearer token issued for a username will still be valid even if a new token for the same username is created. In this case, both the tokens are valid.

3) If anyone authorizes from one machine, the token can stay in that machine for a long period and hence any other user can use the site and automatically get authorized. There will be code written for clearing the token from angular code during log off. But, what if the user does not log off.

4) Giving a short life span for tokens makes sense. However this application is an internal application which is authenticated against Windows AD. So, the users would like the login to stay as it is and not log off and login again every half an hour of idle time or so.

What I would like to achieve is:

1) At the very least, ff a user is logged in, the access token previously generated for the same user needs to be invalid. We will need to have a DB table(maybe called UserToken) and manually store and check it for achieving this. If this is achieved, at the very least, a user logging in another machine will have the access token rejected once he logs in back to his original machine.

(User can login with any valid AD account as this project is having authentication type none and it is authenticated against the AD from a login form).

I am not sure what all other things should be considered.

Any thoughts/suggestions are welcome.

(I tried to look a bit at refresh tokens but since it is a client application, not sure where I can save the refresh token and use in an effective way.)

Answer (score 0):

Check this [How to limit user to only one access token in ASP.NET Identity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49409278/how-to-limit-user-to-only-one-access-token-in-asp-net-identity/49456079#49456079)

and regarding refresh token, you need to save it either in local storage or  in cookies.

Comment: Authentication is against Windows Active Directory and not ASP.NET Identity. Also, I would like to know which is the effective place to store refresh token. If storing in local storage/session storage/cookies is effective, why don't we store the access token itself.